# Notifications and popup windows still in light mode Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, 22.04

So I installed gnome tweaks and also the Dracula theme. In this version it seems that it only allows legacy application swapping. Almost everything works fine except notifications and when I right click on an application it is still in the light mode. I know there must be a way to change it, even with the gtk css but I just have no clue where to look.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color of notifications and window menus are determined by the Gnome Shell theme, not by the GTK theme.

To be able to switch Gnome Shell themes, you need to install and activate the "User themes" extension. This extension is part of the official Gnome Shell extensions, which can be installed with the package `gnome-shell-extensions`.

Once this extension is installed and turned on, installed Gnome Shell themes can be set on the "Appearance" tab in Gnome Tweaks.